# If resistance is very high?

Tags: electromagnetism, resistance, emf

$$ V = IR $$

If there is a conductor with very low resistance, moving in a magnetic field, will it induce low EMF = **IR**? And a high current? Im confused at that point...

Lets assume a conductor having 0.0001 ohms, passes a magnetic field how much EMF can be induced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're mixing up concepts. Ohm's Law isn't a description of magnetic induction. As far as I know, it has nothing (directly) to do with magnetism or induced EMFs. It simply states that if you *already* have an EMF across an (isotropic) object with resistance *R*, the current through the object would be the EMF divided by *R*.

Induced EMFs are a completely different topic. If you have a closed loop of a conducting material, with flux *F* passing through it, the induced EMF is given by the derivative of *F*. The direction of the induced EMF is given by Lenz's Law.

Maxwell's equations generalize induced EMFs to non-"closed loop" shapes.

Answer (score 4):

The induced emf in a conductor hasn't anything to do with the conductor's resistance. On the other hand, if you try taking energy from the induced emf by forming a closed circuit (in order to pass current) then the series resistance of the conductor needs to be low to take more energy most efficiently.

The emf is induced in series with the wire and is proportional to rate of change of flux and number of turns. See [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html) page for more help.